# how to set visible true or false on TextButton in listview

Tags: firemonkey, delphi-10.4-sydney

I'm using Delphi 10.4 Community Edition.

I have 3 items in a ListView with dynamic appearance, and 1 DateEdit:

- 2 textButtons, with name `btnCheck` and `btnUnchek`
- 1 textItem, with name `txtSteam`. This item has a value of 1 or 0
- the DateEdit with name `edtTanggal`

I want that when `txtSteam = 1` then `btnCheck.Visible = false` and `btnUncheck.Visible = true`. But I want to execute this logic in the `OnChange` event of `edtTanggal`.

I've managed to display the desired data in the ListView, but I can't control the visibility of the textButtons.

Comment: "*I can't control the visibility of the textButtons*" - why not? What is stopping you from accomplishing that? Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use UpdateObjects event of Listview

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1UpdateObjects(const Sender: TObject; 
const AItem: TListViewItem);
begin
 if AItem.Purpose<>TListItemPurpose.None then  exit;
 var v:= AItem.Objects.FindObjectT<TListItemText>('txtSteam');
 var btn1:= AItem.Objects.FindObjectT<TListItemTextButton>('btnCheck');
 if Assigned(btnCheck) then
   btncheck.Visible:=v.text<>'1';

 var btn2:= AItem.Objects.FindObjectT<TListItemTextButton>('btnUncheck');
 if Assigned(btn2) then
    btn2.Visible:=v.text='1';
end;
```